# modal showing details - info for buttons which are dynamically created in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC app , and I have a grid of buttons(data cells can also be replaced here instead of buttons) , these buttons are dynamically created, their number and ID is variable.

I would like to show a modal details popup that loads data/information from a JSON file (the file is already in my project), each button has a description node inside this JSON.

What is the best way to create this modal, and have the JSON data loaded into this modal ?  the popup modal here is only informative , and does not have to have any modify/save/delete features, only info display.

The big difficulty for me here is that the buttons are dynamic, and honestly I have no experience for passing arguments between HTML, JQuery , C# ...etc as I am new to Web development.

Comment: can u show what have u done so far?

Comment: The code is almsot confidential and I cannot post it here. 

My question here is only: is it possible to trigger a modal upon clicking on a button, and display information out of a JSON file  .    the button ID should be used to identify which information to get exactly out of the JSON .

Comment: Yes. simplest way is to use ajax. u wanna show like modal dialog on click?